# Accessing Date without creating reference variable

Tags: java, import, java.util.date

We need to create a reference variable of class "Date" if we want to return date.

```
import java.util.*;
class Demo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Date date=new Date();
System.out.println(date.toString());
}}
```

Can we return date and time without creating an object of Date class.

Comment: I don't know what the question means

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a Date object? : S

Comment: Uh, why? Even if you did `new Date().toString()` an object would be created anyway. And object creation is _cheap_. And you forget about JIT.

Comment: Cant we access Date by using static import.. ?

Comment: why is it necessary , not to use date object ???

Answer (score 1):

**No**.not possible.Without creating a `object` you cannot get a date object.

As @fge said at least you can do `new Date().toString()` by avoiding a `reference` *date*.

Instead you can do

`System.out.printlnCalendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());`

Comment: Cant we access Date by using static import.. ?

Comment: Just curious, why you are trying to avoid create a Date object ??Creating an object costs  almost nothing,which takes a little memory.

Comment: No I am not looking for a cost effective way I just want to clear out my concept. As far as I now, with the help of static import we can access the variables of a class directly without creating reference variables, so I was wondering why that concept is not applicable here. :)

Comment: Acha teek hy :) . **In order to access static members, it is necessary to qualify references with the class they came from. **  Please read,http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html.

Comment: You will get a static import,but with out reference how you will use it ??